# Data Acquisition DAQ Hardware?

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering what sort of DAQ hardware people are generally using?  I have various AnalogIO and DigitalIO needs, and bought a National Instruments USB-6211 DAQ.  It turns out that NI doesn't support their USB cards on Linux, nor support any cards on Ubuntu.  (worst case I may be able to run a separate Windows machine with a ROS node to do the DAQ stuff).

Since analog and digital input/output are common among roboticists, is there a DAQ card that works well on ROS and Ubuntu?  Thanks.

Steve.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12739/data-acquisition-daq-hardware?/) by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) on 2012-01-27**:
In particular, I need to do some fairly fast analog output, on the order of a couple hundred kS/sec, on two channels.  None of the NCD devices seem to be very fast, and none of the Arduino solutions are very fast either.  I could use an AVR with a DAC, but I'd like an off-the-shelf solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far I've been able to get away with just using an arduino.  The arduino has a 10 bit ADC, usually with a reference voltage of 5V--so you get a detectable voltage variation of 5/1023 or .0049 volts (4.9 mV), that coupled with a 16MHz process means you can get a respectable sampling rate (in kHz).  It's cheap too (< $100)--that always helps.

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [soheilred](https://answers.ros.org/users/5280/soheilred/) on 2016-03-04**:
In noisy environments, Arduinos don't work well. But these boards are more robust against noise. In addition, for many applications, such as controlling an industrial ac motor, we need to provide a voltage range in [-10,+10], which is impossible to generate with Arduino.

**Comment by [soheilred](https://answers.ros.org/users/5280/soheilred/) on 2016-03-04**:
A solution for the problem that I have addressed is to design an op-amp circuit to....
But, that circuit will not work as good as a prepared package like NI Instruments DAQ cards.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our vehicle has two National Control Devices IOADR8x hybrid relay and A/D controller boards.  This device provides eight relays and five analog to digital converters. Each is controlled by a separate ROS driver node, which publishes current values and handles commands to set the relays.

We bought them back in 2005. I don't know if they are still available, but NCD makes [lots of similar products](http://www.controlanything.com/Relay/Relay/ANALOG_TO_DIGITAL).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2